# xslt always gives me UTF-16 with slashes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, utf-8

I have the following bit of code in C# to convert an XML file to another using XSLT/

```
string xmlInput = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><catalog><cd><title> Empire Burlesque </title ><artist> Bob Dylan </artist><country> USA </country><company> Columbia </company><price> 10.90 </price><year> 1985 </year></cd></catalog>";

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            string xmlOutput = String.Empty;            
            using (StringReader sri = new StringReader(xmlInput))
            {
                using (XmlReader xri = XmlReader.Create(sri))                
                {
                    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    //xslt.Load(xrt);
                    xslt.Load(@"XSLT/slide2.xslt");
                    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                    using (XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
                    {
                        xslt.Transform(xri, xwo);

                        xmlOutput = sw.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

xmlOutput gives me `"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><root> Empire Burlesque </root>"`
How can I get utf-8 and no slashes?

Comment: The are no slashes in actual file.  You are just looking at the way Visual Studio is displaying results.

Comment: A .NET string is UTF-16 so you will get that encoding if you output an XML declaration. Why do you need a string as the XSLT result but want it to declare UTF-8? Are you writing that string later to a file? As for the slashes, that is what Visual Studio shows you in the debugger for a string value, no?

Comment: My XSLT:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:template match='/'>
  <root>
    <xsl:value-of select='/catalog/cd/title'/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: What is the value of `xslt.OutputSettings`

Comment: If you want to write to a StringWriter and get a different encoding then see https://forums.asp.net/t/1436663.aspx?Xslt+XML+Encoding+utf+8+problem

Answer (score 0):

.NET strings are sequences of UTF-16 encoded characters and StringWriter/StringBuilder default to that encoding. (source https://forums.asp.net/post/3240311.aspx)

So you need to make a class which inherits of the default stringwriter:

```
public class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
{
    Encoding myEncoding;

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return myEncoding;
        }
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding) : base()
    {
        myEncoding = encoding;
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding) : base(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    {
        myEncoding = encoding;
    }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(StringBuilder sb, Encoding encoding) : base(sb, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    {
        myEncoding = encoding;
    }
}
```

and create an instance of that e.g. StringWriterWithEncoding utf8Writer = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8); and pass that as the third argument to the Transform method of your XslCompiledTransform.

use like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriterWithEncoding sw = new StringWriterWithEncoding(sb, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(@"XSLT/slide2.xslt");
    xslt.Transform(xri, sw);
}
xmlOutput = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue is caused by StringWriter

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
using (XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
```

Even though you specifically set XmlWriterSettings.Encoding to UTF-8, you specify output stream to be StringWriter and since .NET strings are UTF-16, XmlWriter is forced to use UTF-16. 
If you use for instance FileStream instead of StringWriter, output will be in UTF-8 or whatever encoding you specify.

Slashes issue is just your IDE escaping it. If you print xmlOutput to Console you will see it contains no extra slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this line in your XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>
```

(or of course whichever encoding you prefer), and it will automatically set the output settings to the utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using the MemoryStream is a better way to handle this.  .net strings are utf-16 internally and that's how they are encoded when you write to a StringWriter of StringBuilder object.  Using a memory stream, you avoid that pitfall.

```
string xmlDoc = "";

// Use a memory stream to avoid the .net internal string utf-16 encoding pitfall.
using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlAsText)))
using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltAsText)))
{
    // Transform XML string to new XML based on the XSLT
    // Load the XSLT and transform source XML to target XML
    XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
    myXslTrans.Load(xsltReader);
    myXslTrans.Transform(xmlReader, null, xmlStream);

    // Using the encoding from the xslt, transform the xml stream bytes to the xml string.
    // If no encoding in xslt, defaults to UTF-8.
    xmlDoc = myXslTrans.OutputSettings.Encoding.GetString(xmlStream.ToArray());

    // Remove the BOM if it exists
    string byteOrderMark = myXslTrans.OutputSettings.Encoding.GetString(myXslTrans.OutputSettings.Encoding.GetPreamble());
    if (xmlDoc.StartsWith(byteOrderMark, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        xmlDoc = xmlDoc.Remove(0, byteOrderMark.Length);
    }
}
```

If there is no encoding attribute in the stylesheet, then you get UTF-8 by default, not UTF-16.  This is the same as if you were to write it directly to file.  I can't say how it works for different cultures, sorry.

I'm suggesting this method over the other methods where they are hard coding UTF-8.  This works with whatever (valid) encoding is in the style sheet, such as ISO-8859-1.